# Issue with [array count]

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am a problem with counting values in a plist file ,the problem is the if statement should check if the value is greater than objects in my plist , then stop moving to next pages , here is my code but :

```
    picturesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:
                                    [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"images" ofType:@"plist"]];  
arrays = [picturesDictionary objectForKey:@"PhotosArray"];

    int photoCount =  [arrays count];


if ((photoNumber < 1) || (photoNumber > photoCount)) return nil;

controller = [BookController rotatableViewController];

PhotosInAlbum.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrays objectAtIndex:pageNumber]];
```

but after when photos reach to the last page , application will crash , debugger message :

```
'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (30) beyond bounds (30)'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: `[NSArray count]` gives you the number of items in the array, not the index of the last item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
if ((pageNumber < 0) || (pageNumber > (photoCount-1))) return nil;
```

the reason it crashes is, that count will give the number of objects, but when accessing each, you start with 0, so [array count]-1 is the last index.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
 if ((pageNumber < 1) || (pageNumber > photoCount)) return nil;
```

to

```
 if ((pageNumber < 0) || (pageNumber >= photoCount)) return nil;
```

If you have 30 items in your array, the largest accessible index is 29 because the first element is at index 0.

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
if ((pageNumber < 0) || (pageNumber >= photoCount)) return nil;
```

Since it starts at 0 and if you try to get object at index equal to the count, it's reading past the end of the array.